# How to get header value in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am using strong loopback api for ios app. I want header value.Can any one help me for that

Comment: instead of switching database u could have done something like diffrent records in db for diffrent domains. As switching database is like not proper per request (in other word its not possible).

Comment: this is a crm based app and it is connect with different domains like
www.abc.com, www.xyz.com all domain have different db so that  need to change dB

Comment: so you better build diffrent backend app for diffrent domain :)